# creating a list of files with file absolute path in linux

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a large sum of files (~50000 files).

ls /home/abc/def/

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
.........
.........
file50000.txt
```

I want to create a CSV file with two columns: first column provides the filename and the second provides the absolute file path as:

output.csv

```
file1.txt,/home/abc/def/file1.txt
file2.txt,/home/abc/def/file2.txt
file3.txt,/home/abc/def/file3.txt
.........................
.........................
file50000.txt,/home/abc/def/file50000.txt
```

How to do this with bash commands. I tried with ls and find as

```
find /home/abc/def/ -type f -exec ls -ld {} \; | awk '{ print $5, $9 }' > output.csv
```

but this gives me absolute paths. How to get the output as shown in output.csv above

Comment: _but this gives me absolute paths_ : Hmmm, further up in your question, you write, that you do want to create absolute pathes. So what's the problem then? BTW, what is the effect you want to see, if you have a filename which contains a space or a newline? In both cases your awk script would pick up the wrong fields from the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$ find /path/ | awk -F/ -v OFS=, '{print $NF,$0}'
```

Add proper switches to `find` where needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can get both just the filename and the full path with GNU `find`'s `-printf` option:

```bash
find /home/abc/def -type f -printf "%f,%p\n"
```

Pipe through `sort` if you want sorted results.

Answer (score 0):

if u wanna fully canonicalize all existing paths, including fixing duplicate `/` and resolving symlinks out to their physical  why not just

> ```
>    find … -print0               |
> or
>    gls --zero                   |
> or 
>    mawk 8 ORS='\0' filelist.txt |
>
>            xargs -0 -P 8 grealpath -ePq
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In plain `bash`:

```
for file in /home/abc/def/*.txt; do printf '%s,%s\n' "${file##*/}" "$file"; done
```

or,

```
dir=/home/abc/def
cd "$dir" && for file in *.txt; do printf '%s,%s\n' "$file" "$dir/$file"; done
```